# Journey Contact Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a Journey which has two decision splits based on the status field. If Status =20 one path and if status = 40 then the second path. The Journey setting is to allow contact to renter anytime.

If the same contact enters in the journey at same time, ie personcontact id 1234, status = 20 and personcontact id 1234, status = 40, the contact enters in the Journey 2 times, however, it only takes the value both time as personcontact id 1234, status = 20

Expected result should be the journey should inject the contact two times with different status values.

Is there a way to achieve this expected result?

Comment: Does the Status field you're evaluating come from the Journey data or Contact data?

Comment: @Chandan, I believe you would have used contact data that is the reason it is always going into status = 20.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the contact data in decision split which was causing this specific issue. Followed the approach in as described in below link and the issue is resolved.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_attribute_comparison.htm&type=5

When I compared the Journey data and contact data in the decision split, it provided only one record.

In my case, there is an attribute value orderid which is always unique per row in data extension, and this is what is used in a decision split where I compared the Journey data and contact data.